# Почему списковая инициализация не запрещает сужение типа в C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, типы-данных, g++

По стандарту C++11 списковая инициализация должна запрещать сужение типа. Однако компилятор g++ (версия 4.8.1) без ошибок компилирует следующий код:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double d = 1.234;
    int i {d};  //  здесь происходит сужение и потеря точности!
    cout << i;  // вывод: "1"
    return 0;
}
```

Почему компилятор не выдает ошибку?

Comment: проверил, у меня компилятор ругнулся

    warning: narrowing conversion of ‘d’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

    gcc version 4.8.3 20140624 (Red Hat 4.8.3-1) (GCC)

Comment: @DarkGenius: А с какими опциями вы запускаете компилятор? Попробуйте включить все warning'и.

Comment: @VladD, настройки по умолчанию, не изменял их.

Comment: @DarkGenius: А с `-Wall` как?

Comment: @VladD, я выбрал пункт "Очистить и пересобрать проект", и предупреждение появилось. Если в дальнейшем выбирать просто "Собрать проект", предупреждение не появится до очистки.

Comment: @DarkGenius: Угу, просто оно не перекомпилирует уже собранный (даже с предупреждениями) проект, этого как раз стоило ожидать.

Comment: Чтобы не забывать, используйте опцию `-Werror=narrowing`.